# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : one node produced an error: incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, r-caret

I used the following code:

```
me <- fscaret(mov_train, mov_test,installReqPckg = TRUE ,preprocessData = TRUE,
 with.labels = TRUE,  myTimeLimit = 5, Used.funcRegPred = NULL,no.cores = NULL ,supress.output=TRUE)
```

Which  produces this error:

> ---Warnings have been supressed!---- Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    one node produced an error: incorrect
>   number of dimensions

Any help? I saw the same error here and I tried the solution that they post but no use.
I need suggestion about other feature selection packages in R and easy to use..

Comment: You might want to change the tag; `fscaret` isn't formally connected to `caret`

Comment: thanks for your answer , but what do you mean by changing fscaret , which function i should use instead ?